# Permission issue while installing latest mysql server after upgrade from 18.04 to 22.04

Tags: server, permissions, 22.04, mysql

I cant install the latest mysql server on my local machine. Everything was working fine before the upgrade (nginx/phpmyadmin etc) but it seems like it removed some things during that (perhaps I shouldn't use autoremove command) so I decided to install everything again if missing but can't do that with the mysql server.

It fails either during upgrade or install.

`sudo apt install mysql-server`

Terminal:

`Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ... Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present) Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/4: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/5: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/6: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/7: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/8: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/9: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/10: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/11: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/12: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/13: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/14: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/15: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/16: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/17: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/18: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/19: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/20: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/21: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/22: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/23: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/24: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/25: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/26: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/27: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/28: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/29: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/30: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/31: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/32: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/33: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/34: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/35: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/36: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/37: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/38: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/39: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/40: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/41: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/42: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/43: Permission denied Cannot stat file /proc/4090/fd/1023: Permission denied mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log 2023-12-28T13:01:54.636853Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010946] [Server] Failed to start mysqld daemon. Check mysqld error log. Warning: Unable to start the server.`

Error logs:

`2023-12-28T13:01:40.717530Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)  (Ubuntu).`

`2023-12-28T13:01:41.366417Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 76570`

`2023-12-28T13:01:41.378633Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.`

`2023-12-28T13:01:41.756148Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.`

`2023-12-28T13:01:42.736322Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '50700' to '80035' started.`

`2023-12-28T13:01:54.633654Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-013178] [Server] Execution of server-side SQL statement 'PREPARE stmt FROM @str; ' failed with error code = 130, error message = 'Incorrect file format 'db''.`

`2023-12-28T13:01:54.636731Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013380] [Server] Failed to upgrade server.`

`2023-12-28T13:01:54.636750Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting`

Any idea how to fix that? It states that table 'db' has incorrect format. What is that table?

Thanks for any information. I'd appreciate that.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve that. You need to remove EVERYTHING related to mysql-server. Purge is not enough. You need also manually remove related folders etc.